# AngularJS Subtração de Data

Tags: angularjs

Bom,
Como faço para subtrair um dia com o angular

```
 old.endDay = start.startDay;
```

Exemplo:
startDay = 01/05/2017.
endDay = 30/04/2017.

Desculpa me expressei mal.
 na verdade eu queria era tira um dia do startDay e enviar a alteração para endDay.

Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode utilizar a lib moment js para tratar datas. Será bem mais fácil usando essa lib, porque tratar datas no javascript na mão é chato pra caramba. hehe

Comment: Sim mas acho que esse projeto que estou mexendo já tem lib demais, obrigado

Comment: Bruno, alguma das respostas resolveu o teu problema?

Comment: Sim, todas me ajudaram a chegar na solução e a pensar diferente , obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O AngularJS guarda os valores de controles de tipo data usando o [objeto Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do Javascript. Para subtrair duas datas, você pode usar o método `.getTime()` que retorna o número de milissegundos passados entre a data em questão e o 1º de janeiro de 1970 (GMT).

Então, convertendo os dois, você pode subtrair um do outro e achar o número de milissegundos entre uma e outra. Divida o resultado por `(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` e você tem o número de dias entre as duas datas.

```
var dias = (startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime()) / 86400000;
if (dias == 1) console.log("Correto!");
```

Answer (score 7):

Podes usar uma biblioteca ou fazer isso nativamente.

**Usando [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):**

```js
var a = moment('01/05/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(
  a.diff(moment('30/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    'days')
); // dá 1

console.log(
  a.diff(moment('01/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    'days')
); // dá 30
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.js"></script>
```

**Usando JavaScript nativo:**

```js
function dateFrom(string) {
  var partes = string.split('/');
  return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]); 
}

function dateDiff(a, b) {
  var diff = dateFrom(a) - dateFrom(b);
  return Math.round(diff / 864e5);
}

console.log(dateDiff('01/05/2017', '30/04/2017')); // dá 1
console.log(dateDiff('01/05/2017', '01/04/2017')); // dá 30
```

Comment: +1 por utilizar dd/mm/yyyy como pedido pelo OP.

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu descobrir o que estava acontecendo minha data tinha o formato errado quando vinha do banco, então eu fiz isso:

```
    var data_do_banco = start.startDay.replace("-", " ").replace("-", " ").substring(0, 10);
    var nova_data = new Date(data_do_banco);
    nova_data = nova_data.setDate(nova_data.getDate() - 1);
    old.endDay = nova_data;
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.